# How do I get a Cassandra node to show the IPv4 address in the nodetool status output?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm currently working on a cluster with DSE 6.8, but the address part of the picture is showing up as localhost. How can I get it to show the ip4 address?

[Current Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow34x.png)

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: I'll sign up for membership on the site you gave me.
Thank you.

Comment: Stack Exchange is part of the same network as Stack Overflow so you would've realised that you can use the same login. FWIW I've responded to your question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316146/. Cheers!